# .JAR file can't open in other computer

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, jar

Hi I know this is a very common question but mine is different: I made a .jar file from netbeans, which connects to my db perfectly (even when I launch it on another directory in my computer), but when I try to make the same in another computer (after installing the same things to run the DB) it comes this legend: JAVA VIRTUAL MACHINE LAUNCHER: A JAVA EXCEPTION HAS OCCURED. Does anyone know what can I do to make this work? Thanks in advance

Comment: The same JRE version?

Comment: Are all the paths the same on both machines? Are the same bitwise OS, as in 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Paste the whole error log first,pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, the solution for my problem was to install Java Development Kit on the computer that I was going to use to run the application, and the rebooting the computer.

With this thing you will have enough to run the jar file without any complications

Answer (score 3):

open up the command prompt (run --> cmd) and type   javacpl   javaws -viewer

and see if you get any more details about the problem. If this wont work, uninstall and reinstall java

Comment: Hi, i reinstaled the JDK and it finally worked for me, thank you very much my friend